# Jenkins Pipeline release to Perforce

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, perforce

I'm trying to release new maven project version to perforce.
After a lot of research (correct me if i'm wrong) i didn't find any helpful example how to do it so I'm trying to do it manually - meaning I'm changing the version on pom.xml file and trying to submit it using p4publish.

Those are the relevant stages:

```
        stage('change pom version Release')
                    {
                        steps
                                {
                                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: REPOSITORY_CREDENTIALS_ID, passwordVariable: 'artifactory_password', usernameVariable: 'artifactory_user')]){
                                        script {
                                            pom = readMavenPom file: 'main_project/pom.xml'
                                            pom.version = "${RELEASE_DATE}"
                                            writeMavenPom model: pom

                                            def inside_project_pom = readMavenPom file: main_project/inside_project/pom.xml'
                                            inside_project_pom.parent.version = "${RELEASE_DATE}"
                                            writeMavenPom model: inside_project_pom
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                    }

            stage('publish')
                    {
                        steps
                                {
                                    p4publish(
                                            credential: 'PERFORCE_CREDENTIALS_ID',
                                            publish: [$class: 'SubmitImpl', delete: false, description: 'Submitted by Jenkins. Build: ${BUILD_TAG}', onlyOnSuccess: false, reopen: false],
                                            workspace: [
                                                    $class: 'ManualWorkspaceImpl',
                                                    charset: 'none',
                                                    name: 'jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-submit',
                                                    pinHost: false,
                                                    spec: [
                                                            allwrite: true,
                                                            clobber: false,
                                                            compress: false,
                                                            line: 'LOCAL',
                                                            locked: false,
                                                            modtime: false,
                                                            rmdir: false,
                                                            streamName: '//PROJECT_LOCATION_ON_PERFORCE',
                                                            view: '',
                                                            serverID: '',
                                                            type: 'WRITABLE'
                                                    ]
                                            ])
                                }
                    }
```

My project hierarchy is :

```
   PROJECT_LOCATION_ON_PERFORCE:
              main_project:
                     inside_project:
                                 ....
                                 pom.xml
                     ...
                     pom.xml
              ....
              pom.xml
```

I want to change the first 2 pom's on that list, But after running this on Jenkins only the external pom is getting the new version (although i'm not changing his pom).

What am I doing wrong? 
Can you help me with it please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't know about Perforce, but you could simply use the [Maven Versions Plugin's `set` goal](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#newVersion) instead of changing all the pom files manually. It has a deeper understanding about the project structure and therefore might spare you some problems.

```
sh "mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${RELEASE_DATE}"
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Does it submit it to perforce? Do i need to use it with credentials?

Comment: @reut it just changed the versions in you pom files as you did using `readMavnePom` and `writeMavenPom`.

Comment: OK thanks but it is not solving my submitting problem :)

Comment: @reut well, if I read you question, I understand that your problem lies in changing the pom version. If that's not the case, please be more specific.

Comment: @ Michael - you were right.
My problem was probably with the way I changed my pom files, when i did it the way you wrote, the second stage works correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @reut Sounds like a case of Stack Overflow based rubber ducking . Glad it helped.